# ASP.NET MVC AJAX manipulating model

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

i want to write some kind of TagCloud/Selection in ASP.NET 4.

So that I have a list of Tags and I can add some of them by clicking the text.

What is the best approach to do that?

**Idea 1**
Using a model that contains all available tags and selected tags. When clicking a tag the whole model is sent to the controller and the selected tag is added to the list.

I think this will consume much traffic if there are a lot of tags available.

**Idea 2**

Just add the tag as a  like here on stackoverflow.

But how can I update my model then?

How can I post contents of  to the controller?

Thanks in advance

regards

Stephan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of storing a list of ALL tags in your model, just store a list of those which have been selected. Bind that model to your view.

Add a post method to your controller with a string parameter representing your tag. Do some logic.

Then write a javascript or jquery ajax call to that method where you pass in the name of the tag.

If your view needs to update, you may need to replace html with the ajax call.

Or you can do all of this with just a regular post. It just depends on your needs.

Comment: so I would pass the whole model (but without the available tags) + the tag-id to be added in the AJAX call. The controller then returns the updated model?

Comment: Nope. You just pass in the tag-id to the ajax call. Then update the model using the controller method. Now you need to update your view. You can do this by replacing the html on success of the ajax call or completely refresh the page. (But if you completely refresh, you might as well do a normal post instead of ajax.)

Comment: with a normal post, how can i pass the selected tags if they are a <span>?